# How to Install webuzo on google compute engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, centos7

how to install webuzo on google compute engine? and how to access that, i have done create rule firewall, and also i have done watch this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7icVRMDXwY, but same error, my problem is always get respone "cant reached"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The install script shows you an IP address at the end, but that's the cloud-internal address. You'll need to use [the static IP address you reserved](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/addresses/list) during VM creation. If that solves your problem, great.

However, during the process of going through the walkthrough myself to try to help you, I took a moment to read through [the install script](http://files.webuzo.com/install.sh) and I was not impressed at what I saw; two very quick examples of things that concerned me:

```
# Disable selinux
if [ -f /etc/selinux/config ] ; then 
mv /etc/selinux/config /etc/selinux/config_  
echo "SELINUX=disabled" >> /etc/selinux/config 
echo "SELINUXTYPE=targeted" >> /etc/selinux/config 
echo "SETLOCALDEFS=0" >> /etc/selinux/config 
fi
```

and

```
#----------------------------------
# GET the IP
#----------------------------------
wget $FILEREPO/ip.php >> $LOG 2>&1 
ip=$(cat ip.php)
```

As a result, I would not be comfortable using Webuzo myself; rather, I recommend using the [Cloud Launcher](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/) options, such as [these blog/CMS options](https://console.cloud.google.com/launcher/browse?filter=category:blog-cms) instead. (As an added benefit, you'll also avoid having to pay [the license fee Webuzo requires](http://webuzo.com/pricing).)

What exactly are you trying to achieve? We can give you some good recommendations if you let us know what you'd like to end up with.